# Bootstrap password field padding issue

Tags: html, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

It seems that twitter bootstrap has some issues with padding the password field in chrome. This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9bTK.png) is from [bootstrap's documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms).

I've unchecked everything in the chrome developer tools, but no luck finding the issue. Password fields work on other websites. I've tested in incognito mode, without any extensions. Is it just me?

Comment: And what is the problem ?

Comment: There padding to the left of the password field that I can't get rid of with css. The problem goes away when I remove the "placeholder" attribute. To be clear, both the placeholder text and the hidden password text are padded.

Comment: I tested on Chrome, it works as expected. Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5LYWj/
produces:
http://i.imgur.com/llxukZk.png

Comment: Seem ok [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/7326/)?

Answer (score 0):

I use chrome and I have no problem. Have you looked at your css ? maybe you have a propertie who make this error ? If not you can try to override the bootstrap with other css properties as padding, text-align or more.